# Gson - Named Object to Array

Tags: android, json, gson

In the response from the server, the data is structured as named objects. I'm trying to figure out how I would convert it to an array with the details in specific fields.

Example response from the server.

```
{ 
    "Value_1": { "Foo": "True", "Bar": "False"},
    "Value_2": { "Foo": "False", "Bar": "False"},
    "Value_3": { "Foo": "False", "Bar": "True"}
}
```

Example of preferred converted result from the server.

```
{[
    {"Name": "Value_1", 
    "Details": [{"Name": "Foo", "Value": "True"},
    {"Name": "Bar", "Value": "False"}]},

    {"Name": "Value_2", 
    "Details": [{"Name": "Foo", "Value": "False"},
    {"Name": "Bar", "Value": "False"}]},

    {"Name": "Value_3", 
    "Details": [{"Name": "Foo", "Value": "False"},
    {"Name": "Bar", "Value": "True"}]}
]}
```

How do tell gson to convert from the response to the preferred structure?

Comment: Why do you have to convert it..parse it in your code and use the values as you need them

Comment: I want to make my code very generic, so I can change what values I'm fetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this in a fairly clean method using a custom JsonDeserializer. The main thing is `JsonObject.entrySet()`, which gives you the key/value pairs of the JsonObject so you can iterate over them.

First, when building your Retrofit client, add your custom JsonDeserializer.

```
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MyModel::class.java, MyModelDeserializer())
```

And then implement it like this.

```
class MyModelDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<MyModel> {

    override fun deserialize(json : JsonElement, typeOfT : Type?, context : JsonDeserializationContext?) : MyModel {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject

        // Create a new ArrayList to store the values.
        val list = ArrayList<MyModel>()

        // Using entrySet, get each key/value pair. "Value_1: {...}"
        for (entry in jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            val valueName = entry.key // The key, which would be the name "Value_1"

            // Creating a new ArrayList to contain all the data.
            val vals = ArrayList<Pair<String, Boolean>>()

            val values = entry.value.asJsonObject

            // Using entrySet again for each value of the Object.
            for (entry in values.entrySet()) {
                vals.add(entry.key to entry.value.asBoolean)
            }

            // Create a new MyModel, with the correct name and values.
            list.add(MyModel(valueName, vals))
        }

        return MyModel(list)
    }
}
```